# VBA Access use Highlighted fields

Tags: vba, ms-access

In a current access DB users want to highlight a certain range of cells in a column with their mouse, and use this selection in a vba script. (ex. they select a range -> vba script fills this range with a certain value)

Our problem is: How do we define this selected range in VBA? There are plenty of examples where you use VBA to HIGHLIGHT cells, but not how to use a highlighted range in a VB script inside Access.

Is this possible? 
If so, how do we address this range?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: What do you mean by range?  The table rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A form in datasheet view (or a table/query) has [properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb213764%28v=office.12%29.aspx) to get the selected range. The following is mostly copied from online help:

```
Dim frm As Form
Dim lngNumRows As Long
Dim lngNumColumns As Long
Dim lngTopRow As Long
Dim lngLeftColumn As Long
Dim strMsg As String

' Datasheet that has the focus
Set frm = Screen.ActiveDatasheet

' Number of rows selected.
lngNumRows = frm.SelHeight

' Number of columns selected.
lngNumColumns = frm.SelWidth

' Topmost row selected.
lngTopRow = frm.SelTop

' Leftmost column selected.
'** Note: for me, this is always the actual left column + 1 **
lngLeftColumn = frm.SelLeft

' Display message.
strMsg = "Number of rows: " & lngNumRows & vbCrLf
strMsg = strMsg & "Number of columns: " & lngNumColumns & vbCrLf
strMsg = strMsg & "Top row: " & lngTopRow & vbCrLf
strMsg = strMsg & "Left column: " & lngLeftColumn
MsgBox strMsg, vbInformation
```

In my Access 2010, `.SelLeft` is always too high by 1. So if my selection starts in the first column, it returns 2. Not sure if it is supposed to do that.

Note: `.SelTop` and `.SelHeight` work also for a continuous form in **Form View**, when selecting records with the record selectors.

Comment: when table has sub datasheet the first column return 3, and the first column in the sub datasheet return -1.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the input! No matter what we select, the msgbox returns the same values ( 0 rows, 1 n° of columns, 3 top row, lngleftcolumn = empty). Any idea why this is ? EDIT: activeform did not have rows selected, was a subform of this

Comment: @Witloofdc: you need to set `frm` to the subform then.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the help, consider this problem solved! also, after we figured it out we stumbled upon this page: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/294202, for future reference :D. Thanks!